# How to prove that the closure of a connected set is connected?

Tags: analysis

A set A is defined to be disconnected iff there exist open sets X and Y such that
(A ∩ X) and (A ∩ Y) are disjoint, non-empty and (A ∩ X) ∪ (A ∩ Y) = A.
Hence, the set A is defined to be connected if A is not disconnected.

With this definition of connectedness, how can I prove that the closure of a connected set A is connected?

I thought about contraposition but it was not easy.

Answer (score 0):

A topological space $X$ is connected iff any continuous map from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ is constant. If $f$ is any map from $\bar A \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ then $f$ is constant on $A$ since $A$ is connected and hence by continuity, $f$ is constant on $\bar A$.